# Sitecore Web form for marketer not working

Tags: forms, sitecore, sitecore7.2

I am using sitecore 7.2 & I have installed "`Web Forms for Marketers 2.4 rev. 141008`" sucessfully,
now I created an new form have some fields (single-line,telephone,email) when i submit this form it through an error "**We experienced a technical difficulty while processing your request. Your data may not have been correctly saved.**"

Comment: Have you checked logs? Anything more specific there?

Comment: I agree with Marek. WFFM posts more detailed information into the Sitecore Data logs. If you could attach that error message, it will be easier to track down the source of the issue.

Comment: @MarekMusielak & Jay S sorry for late reply,
No log file is created or empty "All Application>Log viewer"

Comment: @JayS , Marek Musielak also in chrome, no error related to this either in network or console

Comment: Wat save actions are there? default there is a save to database, you need a Connection string.. and a forms database. Is the Form report working?

Comment: @JanBluemink yeah, in may case it's default "Save to Database"
I did not updated any connection string or manually created forms database, are they not create on installation, these were not in wffm reference 2.4 pdf

Comment: @syedAhsanJaffri Marek and I are referring to the Sitecore logs. They are stored in your Data\logs folder where your Sitecore application is installed.

You should be able to view the log files from the Sitecore desktop using the log viewer app as well.

Comment: @JanBluemink i did not find any specific database created on my server for WFFM.

Comment: @JayS you are right, i am also talking about these logs, when i save no new log is created

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Sitecore 7.2
In the App_config\Include\Sitecore.Forms.config
There you need to provide a Form database. `<formsDataProvider ... >...`

The installer place a SQL Server database in the (webroot)/Data folder. This DB (Sitecore_WebForms.bak) can you use (restore in SQL server)

For your CM you can also use webservices (for a create item action, run on  master) this can set in the connectionStrings

Comment: You can also add a connection in `ConnectionStrings.config` with `name="wfm"` and this will be used instead of the formsDataProvider

Comment: @jan Bluemink, Thanks for your reply,

Special thanks for Marek Musielak & Jay S too